# convert timestamp to ISO date in Mongodb version 2.4

Tags: date, mongodb-query

I have mongodb version 2.4.10 installed. The structure of the document is :-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d15f245f4dda1e055091ae1"),
    "name" : "test site service", 
    "starFromTimestamp" : NumberLong(1559275200),
    "toTimestamp" : NumberLong(1561867200),
    "uuid" : "ssg-5d15f245f2893825813309"

}
```

I excuted the following code in Mongo shell in order to convert timestamp to ISODate

```
db.servicesitegroup.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    doc.startISODate=new Date(doc.starFromTimestamp);
    db.servicesitegroup.save(doc); 
    })
```

The document got updated and the resultset looks like:-

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d15f245f4dda1e055091ae1"),
    "name" : "test site service", 
    "starFromTimestamp" : NumberLong(1559275200),
    "toTimestamp" : NumberLong(1561867200),
    "uuid" : "ssg-5d15f245f2893825813309",
    "startISODate" : ISODate("1970-01-19T01:07:55.200Z")    
  }
```

If I use the timestamp converter, then the value of 1559275200 amounts to Friday, May 31, 2019 4:00:00 AM . Why is the timestamp not being converted to the correct value? Can anyone guide me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to multiply the timestamp value with 1000 .

```
db.servicesitegroup.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    doc.startISODate=new Date(doc.starFromTimestamp * 1000);
    db.servicesitegroup.save(doc); 
    })
```

The code above gives me the correct output.